# Этапы компиляции в Си/С++

Tags: c++, c, компиляция

Такой общий вопрос, если не сложно подскажите пожалуйста: вот предположим у меня в коде у проекту подключена внешняя .lib библиотека и у нее есть 5 .h файлов соответствующих 5 функциям, в коде у меня подключен этот .lib файл и include <func1.h>, так как я использую только одну функцию из библиотеки.

И вот на этапе компоновки-линковки, когда из объектных файлов собирается окончательный exe-файл, если я правильно понимаю компоновщик должен еще как то добавить в окончательный exe-шник и данные из подключенного .lib-файла.

И вопрос собственно такой: если все вышеописанное более менее правильно, то компоновщик добавляет вест .lib файл или только часть, которая соответствует подключенному func1.h ?

Comment: lib - это набор объектных (obj) файлов. В зависимости от компилятора etc может добавлять либо объектный файл? в котором лежит упомянутая функция, целиком, либо относящийся к ней кусок кода. Но если эта функция ссылается на что-то из другого объектника той же библиотеки - то соответственно, будет подтянут и он. И далее рекурсивно :)

Comment: Наивный линковщик просто добавит весь lib файл не будет заморачиваться.

Нормальный линковщик будет смотреть, какие символы (да, так называются функции и переменные в данном случае) используются и только их включать в результирующий бинарник.

Comment: спасибо, вам, о мудрецы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файлы с расширением .lib используются для:

Библиотек импорта (stubs), содержащих ссылки на .dll для добавления в таблицу импорта получаемого исполняемого файла. При сборке компилятор сначала составляет перечень методов, реализация которых отсутствует в собираемом исполняемом файле (undefined references), а затем пытается заполнить его из .lib файла.

Библиотек статических, содержащих промежуточное представление кода в объектных файлах для добавления непосредственно в исполняемый файл; При сборке эти объектные файлы добавляются к единицам трансляции собираемого исполняемого файла. Добавляется ли из объектных файлов все или только нужное - задается параметрами сборки. На это влияют следующие настройки:

- /GL (опция компилятора) /LTCG (опция линкера) - whole program optimization - генерация машинного кода откладывается до этапа линковки. Включение этой опции на этапе компиляции дает возможность компилятору оптимизировать (в т.ч. встраивать) код исполняемого файла и статической библиотеки непосредственно при линковке, а не в рамках каждой отдельной единицы трансляции. Чтобы это работало должны быть выставлены обе опции.
- /OPT:REF (опция линкера) - непосредственно включает выкидывание функций, которые нигде не используются
- /INCLUDE (опция линкера) - запрещает выкидывание определенного символа (функции или объекта), даже если те не используются.

Answer (score 3):

.lib - расширение для статических библиотек, а статические библиотеки служат такими архивами скомпилировпнных функций. Компановщик лишь достанет из этого архива те функции, которые вы ИСПОЛЬЗОВАЛИ в коде. Таким образом статические библиотеки - способ создать минимальные по весу прогаммы с минимум зависимостей от других библиотек.

Comment: Andrej Levkovitch, а как или откуда компоновщик знает с какого байта и по какой байт копировать из .lib файла данные ? Откуда он берет эту информацию ?

Comment: спасибо, Вам! +1 см к росту бороды

Comment: @Optimus1 это информация, очевидно, есть в самом lib файле

Comment: Andrej Levkovitch, а чисто теоретически получается - вырезать нужный участок .lib файла можно и вручную ? И к примеру использовать его, как некий опкод ?

Comment: @Optimus1 вполне, но не совсем понимаю зачем вам это делать вручную, если есть уже готовый инструмент для этого..

Comment: `.lib` - не всегда статические либы, иногда это файлик с какой-то метаинфой для `.dll` =)

Comment: Andrej Levkovitch, c .lib файлами, эти не имеет смысла. А вот, с .dll теоретически может иметь смысл ? Если есть только .dll, а таскать, как отдельный файл не хочется, то чисто теоретически можно было бы попробовать из .dll вытащить бинарник нужной функции. Но подозреваю, это не так просто, как кажется.

Comment: @megorit виндузятники и их проблемы))) собственно, все должны понимать, что расширение файлов, это просто имена, они служат лишь как вспомогательные маркеры, не более. Так вы сами можете задать свой суффикс или приставку для библиотеки, или создать текстовый файл с суффиксом .lib

Comment: @Optimus1 с динамическими дибами это не прокатит - на то и существует разделение на статические и динамические либы

Comment: Andrej Levkovitch, но ведь из dll все равно, как то импортируется бинарный код отвечающий за ту или иную функцию.

Comment: @Optimus1 нет, из динамических либ ничего не вырезается, они используются целиком